# Bluetooth Stops Working After Some Time, Reboot Fixes It - for Some Time

Tags: bluetooth, 20.04

I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 on an older laptop that used to run Windows. When running Windows Bluetooth was stable. On Ubuntu 20.04 Bluetooth powers off after using the laptop for some time. Sometimes its ½ hour, at other times several hours, but then, suddenly, Bluetooth gets powered off and cannot be powered on again.

I have tried using `bluetoothctl` to turn the power back on again, but I get different answers. Sometimes it says *"Changing power succeded"* even though it does not, at other times it says something like failed (will add the correct line when it happens the next time).

My system configuration is as follows:

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 35)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 35)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Power Management Controller (rev 35)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series USB xHCI Controller (rev 35)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 35)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 35)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #1 (rev 35)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCI Express Port #3 (rev 35)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx Series PCU (rev 35)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/N3xxx SMBus Controller (rev 35)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev cb)
```

I have been running Windows my entire life, and this is an attempt to switch to Linux. I must admit it has been made a lot easier then before with this build.

I would really like to solve this issue and will provide any information about the system needed to aid me.

Recently I got this message after 45min of of bluetooth being connected:

```
bluetoothctl Agent registered
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:35:7F:61 Connected: no
[CHG] Controller 7C:5C:F8:F3:CD:51 Powered: no
[CHG] Controller 7C:5C:F8:F3:CD:51 Discovering: no
[CHG] Controller 7C:5C:F8:F3:CD:51 Pairable: no
[bluetooth]
# power on [bluetooth]
# power off Changing power off succeeded [bluetooth]
# power on Changing power on succeeded
Failed to set power on: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

And this event get logged, when the connection fails: `drops: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f`

```
sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
[    6.595832] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    6.595923] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    6.595932] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    6.595935] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    6.595943] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.877274] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 3707100180012d0d00
[    6.881131] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq
[    7.066253] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[    7.081277] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[   10.332093] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   10.332096] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   10.332104] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   47.340916] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[   47.340926] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[   47.354895] input: Logitech Bluetooth Mouse M555b Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:046D:B009.0001/input/input11
[   47.355648] hid-generic 0005:046D:B009.0001: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v4.19 Mouse [Logitech Bluetooth Mouse M555b] on 7c:5c:f8:f3:cd:51
[   56.928757] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   56.928769] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   56.928780] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[ 1342.898738] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 3707100180012d0d00
[ 1342.898747] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq
[ 1343.083723] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[ 1343.098752] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[ 1346.358720] input: Logitech Bluetooth Mouse M555b Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:046D:B009.0002/input/input13
[ 1346.360283] hid-generic 0005:046D:B009.0002: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v4.19 Mouse [Logitech Bluetooth Mouse M555b] on 7c:5c:f8:f3:cd:51
```

```
lsusb -v | grep -A 10 -i blue
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
  bDeviceProtocol         1 Bluetooth
  bMaxPacketSize0        64
  idVendor           0x8087 Intel Corp.
  idProduct          0x07dc 
  bcdDevice            0.01
  iManufacturer           0 
  iProduct                0 
  iSerial                 0 
  bNumConfigurations      1
  Configuration Descriptor:
    bLength                 9
--
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x81  EP 1 IN
        bmAttributes            3
          Transfer Type            Interrupt
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0040  1x 64 bytes
--
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0000  1x 0 bytes
--
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0009  1x 9 bytes
--
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0011  1x 17 bytes
--
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0019  1x 25 bytes
--
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0021  1x 33 bytes
--
      bInterfaceProtocol      1 Bluetooth
      iInterface              0 
      Endpoint Descriptor:
        bLength                 7
        bDescriptorType         5
        bEndpointAddress     0x03  EP 3 OUT
        bmAttributes            1
          Transfer Type            Isochronous
          Synch Type               None
          Usage Type               Data
        wMaxPacketSize     0x0031  1x 49 bytes
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get device qualifier: Resource temporarily unavailable
can't get debug descriptor: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Running the command suggested by Adupa:

```
uname -a; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware; lsmod | grep bluetooth
Linux axbuntu 5.4.0-33-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 21 12:53:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev cb)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4c70]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:57b5 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB Camera
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    6.491119] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    6.502736] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    6.502744] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    6.502747] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    6.502770] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    6.719436] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 3707100180012d0d00
[    6.723005] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq
[    6.926410] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f
[    6.941453] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
[   12.064240] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   12.064243] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   12.064250] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   46.652461] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[   46.652474] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[   46.674697] input: Logitech Bluetooth Mouse M555b Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:256/0005:046D:B009.0001/input/input11
[   46.678068] hid-generic 0005:046D:B009.0001: input,hidraw0: BLUETOOTH HID v4.19 Mouse [Logitech Bluetooth Mouse M555b] on 7c:5c:f8:f3:cd:51
[   59.322839] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   59.322850] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   59.322862] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[    0.160706] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.245143] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    6.039318] elan_i2c i2c-ELAN1000:00: Elan Touchpad: Module ID: 0x0005, Firmware: 0x0004, Sample: 0x000d, IAP: 0x000e
[    6.505681] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.3216344376.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.723005] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Bluetooth firmware file: intel/ibt-hw-37.7.10-fw-1.80.1.2d.d.bseq
[    6.941453] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel firmware patch completed and activated
bluetooth             581632  36 btrtl,hidp,btintel,btbcm,bnep,btusb,rfcomm
ecdh_generic           16384  2 bluetooth
```

Can't really figure out what that should tell me, but I ran the update too. I'll be testing during the day to see if that solved the issue.

UPDATE:
Unfortunately the issue persists after updating the driver.

Comment: Just happend after working 45 minutes:
```
bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:35:7F:61 Connected: no
[CHG] Controller 7C:5C:F8:F3:CD:51 Powered: no
[CHG] Controller 7C:5C:F8:F3:CD:51 Discovering: no
[CHG] Controller 7C:5C:F8:F3:CD:51 Pairable: no
[bluetooth]# power on
[bluetooth]# power off
Changing power off succeeded
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
Failed to set power on: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```
Machine has been turned on for more the 24 hours, just being idle.

Rebooting - wishing there was a way to reconnect bluetooth without having to

Comment: Seems like this event is logged, when the connection drops: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f

Comment: Now it happened again: Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected event for opcode 0xfc2f - in bluetoothctl it still says powered: yes under show.
When trying to set Discoverable on I get:Failed to set discoverable on: org.bluez.Error.Failed
After toggeling power off, i get this on power on: Failed to set power on: org.bluez.Error.Failed

Comment: After a wipe and reinstall with no extras on the machine, the issue persists.

Comment: bluetoothctl:
[Logitech Bluetooth Mouse M555b]# power off
Changing power off succeeded
[CHG] Device 00:1F:20:35:7F:61 Connected: no
[CHG] Controller 7C:5C:F8:F3:CD:51 Powered: no
[CHG] Controller 7C:5C:F8:F3:CD:51 Discovering: no
[CHG] Controller 7C:5C:F8:F3:CD:51 Class: 0x00000000
[bluetooth]# power on
Failed to set power on: org.bluez.Error.Failed
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded

Comment: Bonus info: Reboot does not work, when this issue occurs. I have to Power Off and start the machine again. If I choose reboot, it hangs until I cut the power.

Comment: `lsusb | grep -i blue` please.

Comment: Please do not provide additional information via the comments section, but edit your question instead. This will make it much easier for others to read it and thus to answer your question.

Comment: This error is probably caused by an incompatible driver. Please add output of ```sudo dmesg | grep -i blue``` to your question, as well as the output of ```lsusb -v | grep -A 10 -i blue```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comments. I have updated the original question with the requested output.

Comment: Try this to update the driver


     `uname -a; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i bluetooth; dmesg | grep -i firmware; lsmod | grep bluetooth`

output says the version. Mine was BCM43142A0-0a5c-216d.hcd

You can install the new one by 

    `cd /lib/firmware/brcm`
    `sudo wget https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/raw/master/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216d.hcd`

And reboot the system

Comment: Thanks for your reply @AdupaVasista I have updated the question with your suggestions

Comment: @AdupaVasista, unfortunately that did not fix the issue

Comment: Related issue with possible answers:
https://askubuntu.com/q/1250594/323082